# Fokker Planck - Uncertain Parameters

Tags: probability, probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, random-variables

So I came across the use of Perron-Frobenius operators along with Stochastic Liouville equation to propagate probability density function (PDF). This is done by propagating probability density of sampled trajectories and reconstructing the PDF at the end of propagation. The issue is that, the probability of the sampled trajectories of divergence-free dynamical systems, according to the Fokker-Planck equation are constants in time.

Consider a very basic dynamical system:

$\dot{x} = a$

$\dot{a} = 0$

where a is constant in time and considered as parametric uncertainty in the system.

Applying method of characteristics gives the following ODE for propagating the density along the sampled trajectory:

$\frac{dp}{dt} = - (\frac{\partial f_{1}}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial f_{2}}{\partial x_{2}})p$

which is zero for the problem at hand since the partial derivatives are zero.

I also know that the integral of the PDF should always be 1, however if the density is constant along trajectories and the x domain spreads as time goes on, the integral goes to infinity rather than being equal to 1. I was expecting to see a decrease in the probability of the sampled trajectories so that as x spreads the integral over the new domain would be equal to 1, I am having a hard time to understand the paradox here. Can you help me?